# Locked down hosted API to receive requests from one origin

Tags: iis

I have an .net core api api hosted in IIS 8.5.
I want to allow requests from only a certain domain to reach the api.

I have looked at the IIS Rewrite module and see that rules can be setup in there. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by certain domain? Are yu referring to domain in your http hostname e.g www.example.com ,blog.example.com etc. And you want to allow only if the call is from www.example.com?    Are are you referring active directory domain of the client ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually find that your web page won't be able to talk to the API right off the bat anyway. This is a form of security so that javascript on a page can't/shouldn't just be able to call out to another domain.

This is called Same-Origin policy, meaning that any script on a page can only make HttpRequests to the same domain. Mozilla explains it better than I can here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

So your question actually is, how can I open up my API to cross origin calls, but only for my particular domain. And .net core has got you covered!

First install the following Nuget package :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
```

Next in the ConfigureServices method of your startup.cs, you need to add the CORS services.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

Now you need to add CORS to your pipeline.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors( options => options.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod() );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Now your API project should allow cross domain calls, but only for your domain. Of course this does not stop people manually calling your API, but it means that malicious scripts on a domain not under your control cannot make calls unbeknown to the user.

More info : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/03/enabling-cors-asp-net-core/